# Waiting for API call without using async await. Need to maintain a user initiated execution context after the call completes

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, applepay

I'm seriously stuck here, i'm setting up ApplePay that requires a user initiated event to create an AppleSession, but i need to do a series of API calls before that happens, unfortunately due to business rules they can only happen once the user hits checkout.

So the flow is checkout method gets called, in that method we do an await as the process action gets called, then provided it is successful we initialize ApplePay. Looks something like this.

```
checkout( event ) {
    await this.processPayments();
    this.checkoutAP();
}
```

This fails with an error from ApplePay that it needs a user initiated event to create an ApplePaySession. The await returns a promise and wraps any code following it in it's .then. So the call to checkoutAP no longer has a user initiated event in it's stack/context. So it fails.

I tried using a setInterval and check the state value, it will be updated once the process call is done. The code doesn't wait for a setInterval unless you wrap it in a promise, which brings me back to the same issue.

This is my current hacky mess that doesn't work.

```
    await this.processAmenityPayments(this.getPaymentList()).then(( result ) => {
      this.paymentsProcessStatus = PAYMENTS_PROCESS_STATUS_COMPLETE;
    }, ( error ) => {
      this.paymentsProcessStatus = PAYMENTS_PROCESS_STATUS_ERROR;
      this.errors.push(error);
    });

    let intervalCount = 0;
    const interval = setInterval(()=> {
      if( this.paymentsProcessStatus === PAYMENTS_PROCESS_STATUS_COMPLETE || this.paymentsProcessStatus === PAYMENTS_PROCESS_STATUS_ERROR) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        // I can't put it here, it's a different context and fails. 
      }
      intervalCount++;
      if( intervalCount > 20 ) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        return null;
      }
    }, 1000 );

    // my hope is i can wait for the mess to run above, once the state has been updated then 
    // allow the code to continue at this point. 
    this.continueCheckout();
```

Any ideas, no matter how hacky would be most welcome.

Thanks Guys!

Comment: If the ApplyPay operation must be kicked off directly by an end user action, then you will not be able to run it from your code right after some other asynchronous operation completes because (as you've already found out), Safari will not consider that a direct end user action.

Comment: One possible work-around is to get the results of `this.processAmenityPayments(this.getPaymentList())` ahead of time so that you already have that data sitting around.  Then, you don't have to do an asynchronous operation before you run the ApplePay part of things.

Comment: Another possible work around is to add another end-user step to the process.  Step 1 is to run `await this.processAmenityPayments(this.getPaymentList())` and then when that completes, you ask the user to press another button to kick off the ApplyPay stuff.

Comment: mixing of `await`, `.then` and `setInterval` is hacky indeed!

Comment: Appreciate the feedback guys, actually answered my own question, the stack wasn't my issue, it was time. The ApplePay code grabs the time of the user initiated button event, and if the call to initiate the ApplePaySession object takes longer then 500ms it fails. There is no getting around this issue that i can see. So, i'm recommending a complete rethought of the flow. @j

Comment: @jfriend00 unfortunately business rules requires the process call on user checkout, hits the button, process, then go down the selected payment flow. Since we can void process payments but not AP, we want to make sure no errors in process before continuing. This now seems impossible and other options will be discussed in detail on monday, thought about some of your ideas. They will be brought up.

Comment: @Thankyou LOL, yeah, my level of desperation was clearly palpable.